# Knockout-Validations vs jQuery-Validations

Tags: mvvm, jquery-validate, client-side-validation, knockout-validation

I am developing an ASP.Net WebAPI project and using Knockout.js for client-side MVVM. I was considering about client-side validations now and found out [Knockout-Validations](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation). Since this is a recommended validation framework from Microsoft also, I am willing to use this in my project but I am kind of considering about [jQuery Validations](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) as well.

So what  if I use Knockout-Validation instead of jQuery Validations? I mean, Knockout-Validations were pretty new to field but jQuery Validations were there since 2006. What would I miss if I use Knockout-Validations instead of jQuery Validations? Are there some things that jQuery Validations can do that Knockout-Validations cannot do?

FYI, the customer of my project is expecting this product to be used for the next decade. So even the validation framework of choice would also be a very important decision.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Knockout validation plugin uses  "jquery validation" under the bonnet, but just encapsulates it  nicely within knockouts extenders  framework. This encapsulates the necessary jquery validation you mention, have a look at the knockout extenders docs towards the bottom 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html